# How to work multiple bootstrap collapse navbar in a page.?

Tags: jquery, navbar

I want to use multiple "navbars" in one page.
How is it possible when I click on a button to hide another Opened "Div"
I mean once a "navbar" is open.
This is currently working, but as soon as I am open and click on the second button. the first open div not close.

> **like an accordion**

this is my code >>

```
<div class="collapseForMobile  collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar0002">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
            <a data-dbparse="true" data-cntrlgrp="3">
                <span>Print</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
            <a data-dbparse="true" data-cntrlgrp="3">
                <span>Detail Print</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="collapseForMobile  collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar0001">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
            <a data-dbparse="true" data-cntrlgrp="3">
                <span>Upload</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
            <a data-dbparse="true" data-cntrlgrp="3">
                <span>Bill</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-primary navbar-toggler hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar0002"
        aria-controls="navbar0002" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span>Print</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar0001" aria-controls="navbar0001"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span>e-Way Bill Portal</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
        <span>Other Button</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
        <span>Other Button</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a runnable code snippet on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ujagarsingh/pr32yzdk/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the working snippet below, I added below extra js code only.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
});
```

```css
.footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 60px;
            line-height: 60px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

     
        .collapseForMobile .dropdown-menu.navbar-nav {
            bottom: 0;
            top: auto;
            margin-bottom: 60px;
        }

        .collapseForMobile .dropdown-submenu {
            position: relative;
        }

        .collapseForMobile .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            margin-top: -1px;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
     
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">


</head>

<body>


    <div class="collapseForMobile  collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar0002">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
                <a data-dbparse="true" data-cntrlgrp="3">
                    <span>Print</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
                <a data-dbparse="true" data-cntrlgrp="3">
                    <span>Detail Print</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapseForMobile  collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar0001">
        <ul style="left:160px" class="dropdown-menu navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
                <a data-dbparse="true" data-cntrlgrp="3">
                    <span>Upload</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu">
                <a data-dbparse="true" data-cntrlgrp="3">
                    <span>Bill</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar0002"
                aria-controls="navbar0002" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>Print</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar0001" 
                aria-controls="navbar0001" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>e-Way Bill Portal</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <span>Other Button</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <span>Other Button</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it without javascript. See a workable example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uczydz4a/1/).

I added `navbar0002` class to `#navbar0002` div and `navbar0001` class to `#navbar0001` div. Then I changed the `data-target` attribute for *Print* button

```
data-target=".navbar0002, .collapse.show"
```

and the `data-target` attribute for *e-Way Bill Portal* button

```
data-target=".navbar0001, .collapse.show"
```